# How can I set my non-convex object's collision to a more detailed one to allow other objects to go underneath?

Tags: unreal-4, meshcollider

My problem is simple. I imported a 3D object (it's not convex) and I want the character to go under your legs.

[image]

But this does not happen:

[image]

There seems to be a way to do this, I just do not know which one.

Vision of what would be a complex collision:

[image]

I've already changed all these options, but it did not work out:

[image]

The closest I got was when I saw something about adding a physical material. But when I try only a circle appears, I still can not add one exactly equal to the Character:

[image]

Links where I've already looked for help:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Content/FBX/StaticMeshes#collision
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Physics/PhysicalMaterials/PhysMatUserGuide
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/18509-how-can-i-make-this-have-a-more-precise-collision-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collision box defined by the UE4 for any imported object will be as simple as possible.

To modify the collision box I had to follow the following steps:

[image]

Now just click collision and then Auto Convex Collision:

[image]

Now just set the parameters and then click Apply:

[image]

**OBS** - These numbers come by default, I did not put those values ​​to modify my character.

Clicking on apply you will get a preview of how the collision box is:

[image]

**Do not forget to save!**

I recommend not to greatly increase the first parameter if the third parameter is at 100000, otherwise this warning will appear. Certainly not good.

[image]

Result in game:

[image]

References:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/389593/how-to-add-collision-to-a-complex-static-mesh.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm